# Pivotal door - how is the load distributed?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

A pivotal door, where instead of the door hung or cantilevered from the hinges screwed to the frame, the door is hung using a top and bottom pivot.

The bottom pivot assembly's the floor-spring is fixed to the ground and the top-pivot assembly's pivot is attached to the frame.

What portion of the load or weight of the door is transferred to the top-pivot and thus the frame ? And what portion of the load is transferred to the bottom pivot ?